Current slot not in order?
Very simple code:
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 300));
            const current_slot = await conn.getSlot("processed");
            console.log("Current slot: ", current_slot);

I was surprised to see in the output that the slot doesn't continuously tick upwards like I expected, it has periods where it goes backwards or even skips a bunch at once.
I believe this is a core Solana concept that I'm missing but any insight would be appreciated.


This is caused (the most probably) by fact the RPC providers hides load balancing under the offered endpoint.
For every request it's a different machine where the request lands. The machines are not in-sync with each other and one can be slower in updating the on-chain state than the other.
I assume that when you use 'finalized' as the finality of the getSlot() call there will be enough time to be all in sync and the slots numbers will be just continuously increasing.

Great insight thank you
